# Wordpress ACF prefilter relationship field

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

In my wordpress post edit view I have two relationship fields and I would like to prefilter the second one depending on the selection of the first one. So it would have to happen immediately whilst editing.

I am aware of the filters https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-load_field/ but as it would have to happen on the fly I kind of need a JS or AJAX solution I guess.

---

Edit:

[image: screenshot]

What I want to achieve is, that after selecting i.e. "Teilnehmer 1" from the first relationship field then in the second field only "Name 1" and "Name 2" are still available for selection.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thanks for your comment. I am afraid that the bidirectional field won't be of any help for me though. I added a screenshot and some more information. Maybe then my problem gets a little clearer.

Comment: So yes you need JS…